# How to parse json without additional class?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have json with only one type which including some properties

```
{"Agreement":{"agreementId":"1","CreatedOn":"2016-09-02T09:25:05","ModifiedOn":"2019-06-30T23:30:00.173"}}
```

I`m using Newtonsoft JsonConvert.

Is it possible to parse it to model like this?

```
public class Agreement
{
public int Id {get; set;}
public DateTime CreatedOn {get; set;}
public DateTime ModifiedOn {get; set;}
}
```

Now i must declare additional class, which contains this type

```
public class AgreementAdditional
{
public Agreement Agreement {get; set;}
}
```

May be its duplicate, but i cant google it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `JObject` class.

```cs
var json = File.ReadAllText("json1.json");
var example = JObject.Parse(json)["Agreement"].ToObject<Agreement>();
```

Although I see nothing wrong with the `AgreementAdditional` class as that's the exact format of your input.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dynamic`.

Using Newtonsoft you can do it like this:

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

And using JObject you can do it like this:

```
dynamic result = JObject.Parse(json);
```

To use the dynamic object, use it using the same names on the json file.

```
result.Agreement.agreementId
...
```

> However, creating a class is still a better choice for code maintenance.

Comment: I think if OP goes this route then the statement would be `agreement.Agreement...`

Comment: dynamic type is not what i want. I will use two classes, thank you for advice!